Printing a specific section everytime search results are matched
I have a pretty basic text file on a Linux machine that has stuff like Chapters, Dialogues and References.
This is what it looks like

Chapter: 1 One: Birds and Trees

Birds are beautiful and trees are amazing and
they are dependent on each other. Birds most of the time
choose to make their nests on trees since trees provide more
stability. One day the bird sat on a tree and said;

Bird: Oh my I'm so tired from all the flying, I should take a rest
Tree: Mr Bird, you seem tired, perhaps you should take some rest, and
here are some fruits to quench your thirst.
Bird: Oh thank you very much!

Reference:               Chapter 1: birds and trees

Chapter: 2 Two: Trees and Fruits

Fruits are very delicious to eat and they are mostly found
in trees. Fruits contain essential vitamins, minerals and loads
of good fibers.

Reference:               Chapter 2: trees and fruits


These are the contents on the txt file. Now say I was searching for quench, I was thinking that it would start from Chapter number upto Reference. So I tried with grep;
$ grep -A 5 -B 5 'quench' file.txt

However, this does not produce the desired output. I was expecting something like this;
Chapter: 1 One: Birds and Trees

Birds are beautiful and trees are amazing and
they are dependent on each other. Birds most of the time
choose to make their nests on trees since trees provide more
stability. One day the bird sat on a tree and said;

Bird: Oh my I'm so tired from all the flying, I should take a rest
Tree: Mr Bird, you seem tired, perhaps you should take some rest, and
here are some fruits to quench your thirst.
Bird: Oh thank you very much!

Reference:               Chapter 1: birds and trees

And also, searching for the word 'vitamin' would print out;
Chapter: 2 Two: Trees and Fruits

Fruits are very delicious to eat and they are mostly found
in trees. Fruits contain essential vitamins, minerals and loads
of good fibers.

Reference:               Chapter 2: trees and fruits

I was wondering if this was possible to achieve through sed or awk.
P.S: Each new line is an actual new line though

One awk idea:
awk -v word="quench" '                                            # set variable "word" to string we are searching for
/^Chapter:/      { inblock = 1; block = "" }                      # start of new block; set flag and clear block

inblock          { block = block (block == "" ? "" : ORS) $0 }    # if inblock != 0 then append current line to "block"

/^Reference:/ &&                                                  # if end of block and ...
block ~ word     { print block; inblock = 0 }                     # word is in block then print block; clear flag
' file.txt

With -v word="quench" this generates:
Chapter: 1 One: Birds and Trees

Birds are beautiful and trees are amazing and
they are dependent on each other. Birds most of the time
choose to make their nests on trees since trees provide more
stability. One day the bird sat on a tree and said;

Bird: Oh my I'm so tired from all the flying, I should take a rest
Tree: Mr Bird, you seem tired, perhaps you should take some rest, and
here are some fruits to quench your thirst.
Bird: Oh thank you very much!

Reference:               Chapter 1: birds and trees

With -v word="essential" this generates:
Chapter: 2 Two: Trees and Fruits

Fruits are very delicious to eat and they are mostly found
in trees. Fruits contain essential vitamins, minerals and loads
of good fibers.

Reference:               Chapter 2: trees and fruits

With -v word="bubble", or when no -v word=... clause is provided, this generates:
-- no output


The inblock { block = block (block == "" ? "" : ORS) $0 }  may be shortened to inblock { block = block $0 ORS } .

@markp-fuso This is just brilliant!! This works perfectly. Thank you very much.

@PrabhjotSingh that will leave block with a trailing \n; 'course, at that point print block would then need to be replaced with printf "%s", block to keep from printing any extra \n on the end

Using any awk:
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; ORS="\n\n" }
{
    block = block sep $0
    sep = ORS
}
/^Reference:/ {
    if ( block ~ tgt ) {
        print block
    }
    block = sep = ""
}


$ awk -v tgt='quench' -f tst.awk file
Chapter: 1 One: Birds and Trees

Birds are beautiful and trees are amazing and
they are dependent on each other. Birds most of the time
choose to make their nests on trees since trees provide more
stability. One day the bird sat on a tree and said;

Bird: Oh my I'm so tired from all the flying, I should take a rest
Tree: Mr Bird, you seem tired, perhaps you should take some rest, and
here are some fruits to quench your thirst.
Bird: Oh thank you very much!

Reference:               Chapter 1: birds and trees


$ awk -v tgt='vitamin' -f tst.awk file
Chapter: 2 Two: Trees and Fruits

Fruits are very delicious to eat and they are mostly found
in trees. Fruits contain essential vitamins, minerals and loads
of good fibers.

Reference:               Chapter 2: trees and fruits

It's important to put awk into paragraph mode with RS="" so it doesn't treat Reference: in the middle of a paragraph (blank-line separated multi-line text) such as:
Birds are beautiful and trees are amazing and they are
dependent on each other. Birds most of the time (
Reference: their schedule) choose to make their nests
on trees since trees provide more stability. One day
the bird sat on a tree and said;

as if it was a keyword, instead Reference: in the above code is only treated as a keyword if it's the first word in a paragraph.
I'm ONLY testing for the keyword Reference: so it doesn't matter what order the other paragraphs before it appear in or even whether any of them are present of not.
If you want to do a string rather than regexp search for the target then change block ~ tgt to index(block,tgt), and make any other adjustments you like to the search pattern to account for full-line, full-word, partial, etc. matching requirements, see how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern.

Good explanation about possible (spurious) appearance of Reference text within paragraphs at the beginning of a line!

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)
~$ raku -e 'my @a; 
            for slurp() { 
                @a = .comb(/^^ Chapter  .*?  <?before \nChapter | $ > /) 
            };  @a.grep(/quench/).put;'  file

OR (more compactly):
~$ raku -e 'slurp.comb(/^^ Chapter  .*?  <?before \nChapter | $ > /).grep(/quench/).put;'  file

Certain someone will post a Perl answer, but here's an answer written in Raku (a.k.a. Perl6). Raku provides high-level support for Unicode, built-in.
Briefly, the file is slurped in all-at-once, and combed through to locate matching records (Chapters). Think of comb as the global-converse of split: patterns(s) are requested and non-destructively selected out. An advantage of combing through with the ^^Chapter .*? <?before \nChapter | $> pattern is that you can still recover individual Chapters that don't have an associated Reference line (important if you're still editing text):
Regex tokens:

^^ start-of-line,
Chapter text,
.*? zero-or-more any-character (frugally),
<?before … > positive lookahead: \nChapter text | or $ end-of-file.

Sample Output:
Chapter: 1 One: Birds and Trees

Birds are beautiful and trees are amazing and
they are dependent on each other. Birds most of the time
choose to make their nests on trees since trees provide more
stability. One day the bird sat on a tree and said;

Bird: Oh my I'm so tired from all the flying, I should take a rest
Tree: Mr Bird, you seem tired, perhaps you should take some rest, and
here are some fruits to quench your thirst.
Bird: Oh thank you very much!

Reference:               Chapter 1: birds and trees


In the final statement grep is used to only return matching records (Chapters). Above Sample Input is same as provided by OP. Add calls to trim, trim-leading or trim-trailing in the final statement to remove surrounding whitespace, as desired.
https://raku.org
